# How @EmbeddedId construct its composite primary key?

Tags: java, hibernate

I know that the composite primary key of @EmbeddedId annotation in Hibernate consists at least of the combination of all object variables of the embedded primary key object.

But do also the reference of the primary key object itself belongs to the composite primary key, so that it is build up from the reference value and the object variables of the embedded primary key object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An EmbeddedId has fields/properties, mapped to database columns. The combination of those fields/properties constitute the ID of the entity, just like the combination of columns constitutes the primary key of the underlying table. The class must implement equals() and hashCode() so that two instances with equal fields are equal.